# Bash: piping STDOUT to paste

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin, paste

Instead of doing this:

```
$ cat input.txt |
  perl -anF'\t|\n' \
       -e'$n=@F-1if!$n;for(0..$n){push@{$$m[$_]},$F[$_]}'\'END{print map{join"\t",@$_,"\n"}@$m}' > output.txt

$ paste -d"\t" paste.file.txt output.txt |
  perl -ne '{while (<>) {$line = $_; $line =~ s/\t/,/g; print "$line";}}' |
  sed 's/\"//g' > comma.delimited.output.csv
```

I'd like to do something more like this, where all the manipulations are done in one command:

```
$ paste -d"\t" paste.file.txt [[
    cat input.txt |
    perl -anF'\t|\n' -e'$n=@F-1if!$n;for(0..$n){push@{$$m[$_]},$F[$_]}'\'END{print map{join"\t",@$_,"\n"}@$m}'
  ]] |
  perl -ne '{while (<>) {$line = $_; $line =~ s/\t/,/g; print "$line";}}' |
  sed 's/\"//g' > comma.delimited.output.csv
```

Basically I want to paste one file to the left of the output of a series of manipulations in Bash, then continue to perform some manipulations.

Comment: One command?  You are using `paste`, `cat`, 2 x `perl` and a `sed`, that's 5 child processes.  Better to do it all in one `perl` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution).

For example, your *second* command can be rewritten as:

```
paste -d"\t" paste.file.txt $(perl -anF'\t|\n' -e'$n=@F-1if!$n;for(0..$n){push@{$$m[$_]},$F[$_]}' 'END{print map{join"\t",@$_,"\n"}@$m}' input.txt) | perl -ne '{while (<>) {$line = $_; $line =~ s/\t/,/g; print "$line";}}' | sed 's/\"//g' > comma.delimited.output.csv
```

This would eliminate the need of dealing with temporary files.

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for. I assumed Bash had the functionality to allow such things, but I didn't know what it was called. Thanks!

Comment: Ugh, except that I'm getting an error because paste cannot parse this. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to redirect the output.

You could do this in your bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 4>&1 > >(exec tee >(exec paste ... > output_file))

[do some things]

exec >&4- # Put it back.
```